# Increase collapsible content size

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I'm trying to create a small button (an options button) that when clicked opens up a menu of options.  However the size of the content when not collapsed is the same size of the button 
I'm trying to increase the size of the li's.  I have already added this in my style to set the width of the button.  I want the button to be a reasonable size that opens up into larger content.

How do I increase the size of the LI's inside the div without changing all li's in my document.

```
.ui-collapsible {
            width:130px;
        }

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="gear" data-expanded-icon="gear">
            <h4>Options</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                    <li>Read-only list item 1</li>
                    <li>Read-only list item 2</li>
                    <li>Read-only list item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collapsible widget is not really designed for this. I think you are better off using the **[popup](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/)**:

```
<a href="#myMenu" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left">Options</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="myMenu">
         <h4>Options</h4>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                <li>Read-only list item 1</li>
                <li>Read-only list item 2</li>
                <li>Read-only list item 3</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/w0bc6wyp/)**